Delete duplicates from a column and not have it affect the rest of the row
This code is deleting the whole row when eliminating the dup.  I want to delete the dup but keep data in the rest of the row in other columns.
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Range("CJ1")
rg.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=88, Header:=x1yes


Note: x1yes should be xlyes - it should be an L, not a One

Still removing entire row

If you don't want the data to shift you can use .ClearContents

That might work for my situation but not sure how the code would look if I first have to identify the dup then clear any subsequent dups in the rest of the column.


Load data into an array, clear the dup. and write output to sheet

Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDup()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "CJ").End(xlUp).Row
    ' load data into an array
    Dim rngData As Range: Set rngData = ws.Range("CJ1:CJ" & lastRow)
    Dim arrData: arrData = rngData.Value
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objDic As Object, sKey As String
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            arrData(i, 1) = ""
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = ""
        End If
    Next
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub

